# Angular ng-repeat issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've this controller:

```
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {

$scope.buttonList = [
    {
        href: "http://ciao.html",
        cssClass: "",
        iconBeforeCssClass: "",
        labelCssClass: "",
        labelText: "ciao",
        iconAfterCssClass: "",
    },

    {
        href: "ciao2.html",
        cssClass: "",
        iconBeforeCssClass: "",
        labelCssClass: "",
        labelText: "ciao2",
        iconAfterCssClass: "",
    }                
];
```

});

This directive:

```
app.directive('widgetButtonList', function() {
var directive = {};

directive.restrict = 'E';
directive.replace = false;

directive.templateUrl = 'modules/directives/widget-button-list.html';

directive.scope = {
    additionalCssClass: "@",      
    buttons : "@",
};

return directive; });
```

The template is the follow:

```
<div class="ap-block ap-button-list-block {{additionalCssClass}}">           
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="btn in buttons track by $index">                 
        <a href="{{btn.href}}" class="{{btn.cssClass}}">
            <i class="ap-button-list-before-icon {{btn.iconBeforeCssClass}}" ></i>
            <span class="ap-button-list-label {{btn.labelCssClass}}">{{btn.labelText}}</span>
            <i class="ap-button-list-after-icon {{btn.iconAfterCssClass}}" ></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the view is like this:

```
 <div ng-controller="HomeController">
   <widget-button-list buttons="{{buttonList}}"></widget-button-list>
```

But otherwise to render two times the template button as i expected, it print 250 time the widget's template without binding nothing. Can someone help me??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to pass the `buttonsList` using a different isolate scope attribute instead of using text-binding. The `@` symbol on the directive definition object indicates you'll be passing in a string, where you're actually passing in an array of objects. Try this:

```
directive.scope = {
    additionalCssClass: "@",      
    buttons : "=" //instead of @
};

<widget-button-list buttons="buttonList"></widget-button-list>
```

[Plunker Demonstration](http://plnkr.co/edit/LD9rrob615yWl41Eo9TJ?p=preview)

And just for the sake of completeness, you could pass in the `buttonsList` as a string, but you'll have to be aware that in the directive you'll be recieving a JSON string. Then you'll need to parse it inside the directive:

```
directive.scope = {
  additionalCssClass: "@",
  buttons: "@"
};

directive.controller = function($scope) {
  $scope.btns = JSON.parse($scope.buttons);
}
```

I don't suggest this second method, but here's the [Plunker Demonstration](http://plnkr.co/edit/YG7krQvOZJFbZ6k0MXnc?p=preview) of that as well.